# Show user only first few seconds of the video for unregistered users

Tags: php, video, video-processing, phpvibe

I have a requirement to show user only first few seconds of the video for unregistered users.

I am using [PHPVibe](http://www.phpvibe.com/) and admin is allowed to upload a large video from back-office and if user is registered to website he can view the complete video. if is not he needs to get resisted to view full length video.

I am new to [PHPVibe](http://www.phpvibe.com/) and if there is any option available where I can achieve this or any Library I can use with this to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffmpeg to cut the file of any length. Also it is available almost in all linux servers and also it is completely free. Sample command for the video cutting will be like this,

```
<?php
    exec('ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 cut.mp4');
?>
```

This will cut 8 seconds of video from 3rd second.

Refer this for complete documentation, https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

Comment: Thanks I have checked if my server has ffmpeg installed or not.

Comment: It should be there if you use PHPVibe. It is in the requirement page of PHPVibe. http://www.phpvibe.com/requirements/

Answer (score 0):

Upload 2 versions of the video; a few seconds long one and the full video. Show either one based on whatever rules your website has.

You do NOT want to get into dynamically modifying a video in PHP in order to cut it off.

Comment: NO only one video will be uploaded from the back-office... if you have any idea how can I clip a smaller video from the large one by PHP or any other library I am open for that option.

Answer (score 0):

The answers received are right. You can always work with the output file name without modifying the PHPVibe database. They use blabla.mp4, you could exchange this for guests as replace blabla.mp4 with blabla_short.mp4 (or the other way around), your choice. Use their videocron.php and lib/class.providers.php

But, depending on the player used, you can also stop the video at playtime. 
See how they do it with the end events and their overlay ads in the cms, file lib/class.providers.php and I think function _jads in lib/functions.php helps also.
You can google the player events for your specific player, all have online documentation.

Hope this helps!